# How do i validate settings using the project manager generated My.Settings in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, validation, event-handling, settings, my.settings

The code below does not work, the error says the method `ValidateSettings` does not have a signature compatable with delgate '`Delgate Sub SettingChangingEventHandler(sender as Object, e as SettingChangingEventArgs)`'

This error shows up when hovering over [...] `AddressOf ValidateSettings`

```
    Private Sub ValidateSettings(sender As Object, e As SettingChangingEventArgs)


    End Sub

    Private Sub frm_Settings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        AddHandler My.Settings.SettingChanging, AddressOf ValidateSettings
        PropertyGrid_Settings.SelectedObject = My.Settings
        CenterToParent()
    End Sub
```

[Im using this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-validate-application-settings)

Comment: Have you added `Imports System.Configuration` on top of your class?

Comment: Nope, i didnt have it, it works now, thank you! btw how did you know? It doesnt mention this anywhere on the microsoft page.

Comment: It's mentioned in the first part of the document you linked: *ApplicationSettingsBase, the parent class of all application settings classes, exposes four events (...)*. `ApplicationSettingsBase` belongs to the `System.Configuration` assembly. Also, it's used quite often :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add `Imports System.Configuration` to the class, as pointed out by a comment on the original post.

```
Imports System.Configuration
Public Class frm_Settings

    Private Sub ValidateSettings(sender As Object, e As SettingChangingEventArgs)
        'validation and notifying user
        MsgBox(e.NewValue)
    End Sub

    Private Sub frm_Settings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler My.Settings.SettingChanging, AddressOf ValidateSettings
        PropertyGrid_Settings.SelectedObject = My.Settings

        CenterToParent()
    End Sub
```